# Deleting duplicate rows with primary keys that are connected to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

A process was causing duplicate rows in a table where there were not supposed to be any. There are several great answers to deleting duplicate rows online. But, what if those duplicates with ID primary keys all have data in other tables tied to them?

Is there a way to delete all duplicates in the first table and migrate all data tied to those keys to the single PK ID that wasn't deleted?

For example:

```
TABLE 1
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| ID(PK)| Model    | ItemType | Color      |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| 1     | 4        | B        | Red        |
| 2     | 4        | B        | Red        |
| 3     | 5        | A        | Blue       |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+

TABLE 2
+-------+----------+---------+
| ID(PK)| OtherID  | Type    |
+-------+----------+---------+
| 1     | 1        | Type1   |
| 2     | 1        | Type2   |
| 3     | 2        | Type3   |
| 4     | 2        | Type4   |
| 5     | 2        | Type5   |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

So I would theoretically want to delete the entry with **ID: 2** from **TABLE 1**, and then have the **OtherID** fields in **TABLE 2** switch to **1**. This would actually be needed for X number of tables. This particular situation has 4 tables connected to its ID PK.

Comment: You should have used unique constraints in the first place to prevent duplicates...

Comment: what it means by "hen have the OtherID fields in TABLE 2 switch to 1" ?

Comment: @stickybit That horse has left the barn.

Comment: @stickybit You can't added them after duplicates already exist. It was just something that was missed during the design

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 OtherID is the foreign key to the ID (PK) in TABLE 1

Comment: @bbaird Exactly. It was something that wasn't caught until too late. The constraints were included in the original mockup, just must have been forgot about during the build phase

Comment: I got that part but when you say "migrate" or "switch" in this case you want to switch to 1, but then 1 also has duplicate even though its not deleted ? could you e specific about this logic of migration ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 TABLE 1 is a one to many relationship with TABLE 2. TABLE 2 can have OtherID duplicated all it needs. TABLE 1 is not supposed to have the same exact information for more than 1 line. There were supposed to be a constraint to prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this automatically.  But you can do this with some queries.  First, you set all the foreign keys to the correct id, which is presumably the smallest one:

```
with ids (
      select t1.*, min(id) over (partition by Model, ItemType, Color) as min_id
      from table1 t1
     )
update t2
    set t2.otherid = ids.min_id
    from table2 t2 join
         ids
         on t2.otherid = ids.id
    where ids.id <> ids.min_id;
```

Then delete the ids that are either duplicated or not referenced in `table2` (depending on which you actually want):

```
with ids (
      select t1.*, min(id) over (partition by Model, ItemType, Color) as min_id
      from table1 t1
     )
delete from ids
    where id <> min_id;
```

Note:  If the database has concurrent users, you might want to put it in single user mode for this operation or lock the tables so they are not modified during these two operations.

Answer (score 1):

To do this right, you want to wrap everything in a single transaction and perform this during a regular maintenance period.  Anything else could leave things as inconsistent as they are now.

1. Make a determination as to which "key" you will use.
2. Update all of the child tables to use the new "key" where the value is the old "key".
3. There should be no FK dependencies on the duplicate records, delete them.
4. Once all ambiguities are resolved, place an unique constraint on `(ItemType,Color)` (or whatever the real columns are).

If there are *a lot* of instances, you may need to write a script to handle this and use the information in `sys.foreign_keys` and `sys.foreign_key_columns` to determine which records to update and in which order.